# How to add category even if it doesn't occur in period?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('day',timestamp),
    device_log_sections.name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    "device_logs" 
RIGHT JOIN 
    "device_log_sections" ON "device_log_sections"."id" = "device_logs"."device_log_section_id" 
WHERE 
    (timestamp >= '2020-02-11T00:00:00+02:00') 
    AND (timestamp <= '2020-02-21T23:59:00+02:00') 
GROUP BY 
    date_trunc('day',timestamp), device_log_sections.name 
ORDER BY 
    date_trunc('day',timestamp)
```

The result is

[image: sql result]

My device_log_sections table has categories ping, oob, connection,disconnection, auth, server.
I'd like to have a result where each category is represented in each timestamp. For example 
server category is represented in each timestamp with 0 value if it doesn't occur within specific period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the results:

```
SELECT gs.dte, dls,name, COUNT(dl.device_log_section_id)    
FROM device_log_sections dlc CROSS JOIN
     generate_series('2020-02-11'::date, '2020-02-21'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) "device_logs" LEFT JOIN
     device_log dl 
     ON dl.device_log_section_id = dls.id AND
        date_trunc('day', dl.date) =  gs.dte
GROUP BY gs.dte, dls.name
ORDER BY gs.dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct SQL

```
SELECT 
gs.dte, 
dls.name, 
COUNT(dl.device_log_section_id)    
FROM device_log_sections dls
CROSS JOIN generate_series('2020-02-11T00:00:00'::date, '2020-02-21T00:00:00'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
LEFT JOIN device_logs dl ON dl.device_log_section_id = dls.id AND
        date_trunc('day', dl.timestamp) =  gs.dte
GROUP BY gs.dte, dls.name
ORDER BY gs.dte
```